# Regex for string without spacial characters or spaces

Tags: c#, regex

In my app I run some scripts, I have something like:

```
void RunScript(string path)
```

I get exeption when there is spaces or spacial chars in the path so I want to validate the path beforehend, I need something like:

```
bool ValidPath(string path){
 return !path.Contans(" ") | !path.Contans(spacial chars);
 }
```

Can you help me with some regex or something else to validate this?

Comment: Linq: `!path.Any(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c));` regular expression: `!Regex.IsMatch(path, @"\s");` if *spacial* means *white spaces*

Comment: "spacial" -> "spatial" or "special"?

Comment: @Rawling Sorry English isn't my 1st language

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `Path.GetInvalidPathChars` instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @JonSkeet  thanks!! I will take a look.